# Kotlin Android Extensions generated functions are never used

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I have noticed that synthetic properties from Kotlin Android Extensions work somewhat strange in some cases. Using them in my activities did not make any problems yet, but in view holders it just keeps calling `findViewById()` instead of `_$_findCachedViewById()` under the hood. Please note that I am using the newest Android Studio with the newest plugins (and the newest Kotlin version).

So, having a piece of code like that:

```
class Holder(override val containerView: View) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(containerView), LayoutContainer {
fun bind() {
    containerView.my_text_view.text = "Hello Stackoverflow!"
    itemView.my_another_view.text = "Foo"
    }
}
```

Results for me in the following code in Java:

```
TextView var10000 = (TextView)this.getContainerView().findViewById(id.my_text_view);
...
var10000 = (TextView)var1.findViewById(id.my_another_view);
...
```

As I can understand, this has nothing to do with view caching, so that is a problem. The most interesting part is that `_$_findCachedViewById()` and `_$_clearFindViewByIdCache()` methods *do* generate in the code, but they are not used.

The following issue persists even on projects downloaded from the web.

Am I wrong thinking it is some sort of a bug? Does the generated Java code really work as intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The View Caching documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#view-caching) states that caching is only done on `Activity`, `Fragment`, `View` or a `LayoutContainer`:

> By default, Android Extensions adds a hidden cache function and a storage field to each container (`Activity`, `Fragment`, `View` or a `LayoutContainer` implementation) written in *Kotlin*.

So you need to implement `kotlinx.android.extensions.LayoutContainer`
 with your view holder. It's still an experimental feature, so you have to enable it:

```
androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}
```

Then you have to call the synthetic properties on the instance directly. Every call to these as a property of `View` results in the uncached calls.

So instead of using `ontainerView.my_text_view` or `itemView.my_another_view` you should use `my_text_view` or `my_another_view` directly.

So using any of `kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.view.*` results in uncached calls to `findViewById()`.

Comment: In my code you can see that I already implemented `LayoutContainer`, so yes, experimental functions are also enabled.

Comment: I added some more information to it. You should not the properties on the views but rather on the container itself.